# Vim Gitgutter to the right of the line numbers

Tags: vim, git, plugins

I am using [vim-gitgutter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter) in conjunction with vim's native line numbers. The problem is, I gitgutter is showing up on the left of the line numbers and I would prefer it go on the right. Is there some way to force the sign to go to the right?

Comment: I want to say no since signs are also a builtin feature of vim. A quick skim through the documentation for signs doesn't show anything either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *gitgutter* plugin uses the *signs column* feature of Vim. Unfortunately, the position is fixed and cannot be changed.

The main motivation for the signs column are compiler errors and debugger breakpoints. I guess the reason that the numbers column is between the signs and the text is that the numbers have a higher affinity to the text, and because they have always (starting with *vi*) been directly together, (and it probably was easier to implement this way, too).